# Is there a way to record and replay audio using pure HTML5?

Tags: html, audio, media

I need to create a proof of concept where users will record and replay audio, but it should be done using HTML5 without any browser plugin. Is this possible today?

Comment: From Wikipedia, HTML5 is a language for structuring and presenting content.

Comment: HTML5 can *play* audio, but *recording* is a whole other thing.  I don't see a browser (without plugins) letting random web sites access your mic -- talk about privacy issues waiting to happen.

Comment: Checkout [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215000/how-to-save-files-locally-using-html5)

Answer (score 0):

for firefox take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Creating_a_Web_based_tone_generator